# Encapsulate the way a particular type of brush is drawn in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, oop, encapsulation, drawrect

I am making a drawing app for iOS and I have the following classes:

- `CanvasViewController` holds a `CanvasView` and allows you to select a `Brush` for use in drawing
- `CanvasView` is a `UIView` that contains a background color and an array of `Stroke` that are rendered by wiring up `touches` events and `drawRect`
- `Stroke` is an `NSObject` that contains a `UIBezierPath *path` and a `Brush`
- `Brush` contains an `int brushType` that is defined by a `typedef` and can be things like `BrushTypeSolid, BrushTypeSpray, BrushTypePattern`

Initially I thought about how I would handle drawing different `brushType` in my `drawRect` and it would be something like the following:

**in drawrect**

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);

if ([squigglesArray count] > 0)  {

    for (WDSquiggle *squiggle in squigglesArray) {
        [self drawSquiggle:squiggle inContext:context];
    }
}

[self drawSquiggle:currentSquiggle inContext:context];

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

**in drawSquiggle**

```
switch (squiggle.brushType): {
    case BrushTypeSolid:
         //solid brush stuff
         break;
    case BrushTypeX:
         //x stuff
         break;
}
```

However, now the drawing logic is all handled in a way that strongly ties the `CanvasView` and the `BrushType` together.

Is there an elegant way to encapsulate drawing logic in the `BrushType` or the `Squiggle` so that I could do something like:

`[squiggle drawInRect:myRect]`

or

`[squiggle drawInView:myView]`

Or, is this a stupid goal to have / I do not understand encapsulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could turn `BrushType` into a class with subclasses for each specific implementation and move the related logic inside `drawSquiggle` to it. `drawSquiggle` will simply call:

```
[squiggle.brushType draw......]
```

(you can certainly find the best name and parameters for this method)

This is a refactoring called ["replace conditional with polymorphism"](http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html).

Comment: Is it advisable to have the drawing logic, ie `[squiggle drawInRect:myRect]` pushed to the `Squiggle`? or actually, `[squiggle drawInContext:(CGContextRef)context]`